# Last 5 days average

Tags: r

So my data looks like this:

```
DATE        Value
    1/2/2004    68
    1/5/2004    92
    1/6/2004    100
    1/7/2004    73
    1/8/2004    71
    1/9/2004    75
    1/12/2004   100
    1/13/2004   59
    1/14/2004   71
    1/15/2004   74
    1/16/2004   54
    1/19/2004   68
    1/20/2004   64
    1/21/2004   53
    1/26/2004   67
    1/27/2004   53
    1/28/2004   58
    1/29/2004   56
    1/30/2004   86
    2/3/2004    79
    2/4/2004    82
    2/5/2004    51
    2/6/2004    61
    2/9/2004    99
    2/10/2004   51
    2/11/2004   61
    2/12/2004   88
    2/13/2004   64
    2/16/2004   99
    2/17/2004   90
    2/18/2004   97
    2/19/2004   61
    2/20/2004   59
    2/23/2004   63
    2/24/2004   64
    2/25/2004   74
    2/26/2004   88
    2/27/2004   93
```

And this goes on for 5 years.

I want to find the average "value" of the last 5 days of each month in R, is that possible?

I hope that was clear.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried and which part of the code is giving you problems? Mind that SO is not the best site to ask advice in general workflow and it's best received if you give a clear programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `df` is your `data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)

df$DATE = as.Date(df$DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y")

setDT(df)[order(DATE), mean(tail(Value,5)), by=list(year(DATE), month(DATE))]
#   month year   V1
#1:     1 2004 64.0
#2:     2 2004 76.4
```

Comment: Cool! and practical question!

Comment: Assigning new columns isn't necessary.  You can do `setkey(setDT(df), DATE)[, mean(tail(Value, 5)), by=.(year(DATE), month(DATE))]`

Comment: Indeed, this is a nice code reduction!

Comment: Nice. There is no need to set key though - `setDT(df)[order(DATE), mean(.), by=.()]` should be very efficient too.

Comment: Oh ok, I use `setkey` to order implicitely but for some people not familiar with `data.table`, `order` is maybe clearer

Answer (score 4):

An option using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gby <-  extract(df, DATE, c('month', 'year'), '(.*)/.*/(.*)') %>%
                                             group_by(month, year) 

gby %>%
      slice((n()-4):n()) %>% 
      summarise(Value=mean(Value))
 #   month year Value
 #1     1 2004  64.0
 #2     2 2004  76.4
```

Or

```
gby %>%
     summarise(Value=mean(tail(Value,5)))
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
  MONTH <- sub('/.*', '', df$DATE)
  YEAR <-  sub('.*/', '', df$DATE)
  aggregate(Value~MONTH+YEAR, df, FUN=function(x) mean(tail(x,5)))
  #  MONTH YEAR Value
  #1     1 2004  64.0
  #2     2 2004  76.4
```